# formato de fecha pdo

Tags: php, pdo, date

hola quiero mostrar la fecha en este formato en una consulta "d-m-Y" ya que cuando la almaceno en la bd se almacena de esta forma "Y-m-d" tipo date anexo un trozo de mi consulta, gracias de ante mano

```php
 `while ($linea = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo "<tr>
<td align=center>$i</td>
<td align=center>{$linea['nombres']}\n{$linea['apellidos']}</td>
<td align=center>{$linea['email']}</td>
<td align=center>{$linea['mensaje']}</td>
<td align=center>{$linea['fecha']}</td>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la función [date](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) y la función [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php)

```
  $date_bd = '2016-12-28';
  echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date_bd));
```

Para tu ejemplo quedaría:

```
$fecha = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($linea['fecha']))
<td align=center>{$fecha}</td>
```

Comment: gracias fabián por tu respuesta amigo, pero me da error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\umom\admin\contacto.php on line 126

Comment: Intentalo de esta forma:

$fecha = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date_bd));

echo "<tr>
<td align=center>{ $fecha }</td>
";

Comment: menos, pero bueno gracias ya tengo mas o menos un ejemplo