# Formato Fecha de una consulta con PDO

Tags: php7, pdo

Soy nuevo en la utilización de pdo para programar. Si me pueden ayudar en darle formato a la fecha que obtiene de la base de datos d-m-y.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM paises"; 
$query = $connect -> prepare($sql); 
$query -> execute(); 
$results = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 

if($query -> rowCount() > 0)   { 
foreach($results as $result) { 
echo "<div>
<div>".$result -> nombre."</div>
<div>".$result -> fecha."</div>
</div>";

}
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de base de datos? Las fechas en las bases de datos deben estar guardadas en campo tipo `DATE`; o en todo caso si las quieres guardar como VARCHAR debe ser en formato `YYYY-mm-dd`. Esto asegura hacer cálculos de fecha de forma fácil y natural. Para mostrar la fecha a los usuarios, solo hay que hacer la [conversión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/49140/80870) respectiva.

Comment: tipo date es el campo de la base

Comment: las respuestas van abajo separado de la pregunta ....